# how to conceive this model in database

Tags: java, mysql, sql, database, uml

i have to conceive the following model:

i've patients and 4 specialities (dermatology, nutrition, Lazer, mesotherapy)

so each patient can belong to one speciality and one speciality can have several patient,

each speciality have it own needed information different from the other and have information in common
dermatology( diagnosis, treatment....)
Nutrition( age, size, weight, treantment, number of session, pathology...)
and so on
my question is how to connecte the patient table which contains the patient information and the specialities tables which contains the information needed for each speciality and do i need to do a heritage for the specialities tables on one comment table

Comment: Nice of you sharing this homework with us. Now... where's the question? Or should it be "can you please do my homework for me"?

Comment: @EelLee this is not a homework i'm just a self tutoring and i want to conceive this problem so i searched asking for help because i'm stuck

Comment: @Adams I see, but have you tried anything? Please try something yourself, and when you will be having trouble with some particular issue, then come back and ask a question. Because how we can help you now?

Comment: @EelLee just an UML class diagram example will be really helpfull, i can't see how do the connection between the DB tables that's all, i don't need coding for now thanks

Comment: maybe you could ask your question here -  http://dba.stackexchange.com/ it's more like database oriented SO site, but I still don't know if they will simply give you the solution. Nobody expects that you will perfectly know what is the problem! Simply **try** it, you know, try what comes to your mind. Just try. And maybe your first try will work the first time, and be the solution you are looking for? If not, feel free to come back and ask a question! Simply write then what are you trying to achieve and what is the solution you tried. That way it will look **much** better. Good luck! :)

Comment: @EelLee thank you for this answer and giving me some of your time

Comment: there is a lot of people here, that want to help, really. They (me too) just don't like when somebody's trying to get the answer, without any effort of his own. If you tried *anything* and you're stuck in the middle - don't hesitate and ask! Simply describe what are you doing, show what have you done and ask the question.

Comment: @EelLee i've tryied to do a class diagram (mainly on paper) but i was really stuck in how to do the relation between classes that was my only problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I understood your question you will have to make 4 tables:

1. Patient Table : Containing Information about Patient like Name,age,contact number etc., Primary key Patient_ID and Foreign key Speciality ID (Primary Key in Speciality Table).
2. Speciality Table : Containing unique Information, Primary key Speciality ID and 2 Foreign Keys Dermatology_ID (Primary key of dermatology table) , Nutrition_ID (Primary key of Nutrition table)
3. Nutrition Table : age, size, weight, treantment, number of session, pathology and Primary Key Nutrition_ID
4. Dermatology Table : diagnosis, Treatment.. and Primary key Dermatology_ID

Then probably you can create 4 classes for each table and connect them (use object). I would suggest you to take some sample Project and try to learn as much as you can from it. All the best.

Comment: Welcome! You may refer this project to know how to connect DB and your classes.. http://www.dotnetspider.com/projects/3-Library-Management-System.aspx

Answer (score 1):

You Question indicates to me that you are not thinking about this the right way.  UML is a **object** modelling language at its core.  You are talking about "tables".  What your need to do the design in terms of object classes, attributes, relations.  Only think about the database tables AFTER you have a object model that adequately describes your information space.

Anyway, the right way to approach learning to use UML is the same for programming.  You do it yourself.  Draw the diagrams, refine them, if you run into a specific roadblock try to figure a way around it.

Comment: thank you, i'm trying to model a class diagram and i'm stuck on how to find the relation between  the two class and if i do a heritage or not